# Using FindRoot to solve for coefficient of LinearModelFit

Tags: equation-solving

I filmed a small object falling and have data representing its height (in feet) with respect to the frame of the recording. A sample of the data is:

```
data = {{1, 0}, {18, -(5/6)}, {35, -(7/4)}, {57, -(10/3)}};
```

If we divide the $x$-values by the framerate (in fps), then fit the data with a quadratic polynomial, the coefficient of the $x^2$ term should be 1/2 of the gravitational constant $g\approx -32\rm{ft}/s^2$.

The camera supposedly shot at 240 fps, so we divide the $x$-values of the data by 240 and find the coefficient of $x^2$:

```
 Coefficient[LinearModelFit[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]]/240, data[[All, 2]]}], {x, x^2}, x][x],x^2]
```

which returns $-18.8398$, which is not $-16$.

Among other possible errors, I'm pretty sure the camera wasn't shooting at 240 fps. I can find the approximate framerate with guess & check or my own programmed solver, but I wanted to find it using Mathematica's built-in solvers. However, commands such as

```
FindRoot[Coefficient[LinearModelFit[Transpose[{data[[All, 1]]/fr, data[[All, 2]]}], {x, x^2}, x][x], x^2] == -16, {fr, 240}]
```

return errors of

```
LinearModelFit: Unable to construct a numeric design matrix. Nominal variables may need to be specified, or non-numeric entries for numeric variables may need to be replaced.
FindRoot: The function value {False} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {fr} = {240.}.
```

This somewhat makes sense, as I think `LinearModelFit` is trying to fit to data containing a variable. I tried to use `Evaluate` in places to force Mathematica to apply a value to `fr` before  fitting to the data, but had no success.

Is there a way to use a built-in solver in a situation like this?

Comment: Maybe `LinearModelFit` is giving a terrible fit and you don't realize this, but `Show[ListPlot[Transpose[{data[[All,1]]/240,data[[All,2]]}]],
Plot[-18.8x^2-9.65x+0.0292,{x,0,57/240}]]` shows a pretty good fit, so that isn't it. Maybe try least squares `NMinimize[(1/fr-0)^2+(16/fr-5/6)^2+(35/fr-7/4)^2+(57/fr-10/3)^2,fr]` returns `{0.0711119,{fr->17.8809}}` and 17.8809 isn't far from 18. So tweak that `fr` to least squares minimize a quadratic and I think you might have it.

Comment: One can't expect much when fitting 3 parameters to just 4 data points.  While the estimate of the coefficient for $x^2$ is -18.8398, the 95% confidence interval is (-66.1898, 28.5102).  So -16 is well within that confidence interval.

Comment: @JimB I only listed 4 of my many data points to simplify the problem statement and give a minimal (non)working example. The heart of the question isn't really establishing the framerate, but rather how can I use `FindRoot` with a dataset that isn't fixed. The title implies that, but I buried that in my question statement among all the info about framerates and gravity.

Comment: OK.  I see.  But you take the prize for the most minimal working example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems easiest to hide the `LinearModelFit` from `FindRoot` by wrapping it in a function defined using `NumericQ`, i.e. that only evaluates when given numerical values of `fr`. I've also slightly simplified the dataset construction and the extraction of the last coefficient, resulting in the following:

```
ClearAll[model]
model[fr_?NumericQ] := 
 Last@LinearModelFit[{#1/fr, #2} & @@@ data, {x, x^2}, x]["BestFitParameters"]

FindRoot[model[fr] == -16, {fr, 240}]

(* Out: {fr -> 221.173} *)
```

This seems a reasonable estimate of the actual frame rate, close enough to the nominal 240.

Answer (score 3):

The frame rate can be estimated directly using `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
data = {{1, 0}, {18, -(5/6)}, {35, -(7/4)}, {57, -(10/3)}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + b t - (32.2/2) (t/f)^2, {a, b, f}, t];
nlm["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Parameter confidence interval table]

But the width of the confidence interval for the `f` (the frame rate) is so wide which renders the estimate of the frame rate to be near useless.  More data points are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way confirming @MarcoB

```
datas = {#1, -16 #1^2, #2} & @@@ data;
lm2 = LinearModelFit[datas, {x, y}, {x, y}];
fps = Sqrt[1/lm2["BestFitParameters"][[3]]]
```

yields: 221.173

Checking:

```
datar = {#1/fps, #2} & @@@ data;
LinearModelFit[datar, {x, x^2}, x]["BestFitParameters"]
```

yields: {0.0291591, -8.89405, -16.}

Comment: It's cool this works, and ... I don't know what's going on! I'm not sure how the dataset of `datas`, with the new 2nd component, is used.